# How to call and store process asynchronously NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Firsly I am new to Nodejs and async code (PHP background)

I have the following code:

```
const getMasterData = new GetMasterData(connection, userUUID);
const syncSorter = new SyncSorter();
const syncToMaster = new SyncToMaster(connection, userUUID);



// All the below async

// User Params
const userParamsMaster = await getMasterData.getUserParamsMaster();
const userParamsSorted = await syncSorter.sortSyncData(userParamsLocal, userParamsMaster, lastSyncTimeStampLocal, 'packageUserParams');
syncToMaster.syncToMaster(userParamsSorted.toMasterData, [], 'user').then();

// Li Data
const liDataMaster = await getMasterData.getLiMasterData();
const liSorted = await syncSorter.sortSyncData(liDataLocal, liDataMaster, lastSyncTimeStampLocal, 'packageLi');
syncToMaster.syncToMaster(liSorted.toMasterData, ['customFieldsID', 'userID'], 'userReminders').then();

//Once all the above finished then continue
```

I want the above to happen async then once completed I can use the combined results

I am wondering how to make this possible?

I assume each section (// ... ) can go into its own function which is async and then within each have the respective awaits but I am not sure.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for **Promise.all** or **Promise.allSettled**

[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
[Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

```
// User Params
// Pipe
const userParams = getMasterData.getUserParamsMaster()
     .then(userParamsMaster => 
           syncSorter
             .sortSyncData(
               userParamsLocal, 
               userParamsMaster,
               lastSyncTimeStampLocal, 
               'packageUserParams'
             )
      )

// Li Data
// Pipe
const liData = getMasterData.getLisMasterData()
      .then(liDataMaster =>
           syncSorter
             .sortSyncData(
                 liDataLocal, 
                 liDataMaster,
                 lastSyncTimeStampLocal, 
                 'packageLi'
              )
       )
const result = await Promise
  .all([
     liData,
     userParams
   ])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not do `await` on an `async` function all, you will receive a Promise back. This promise will be resolved at some time in the future with a success or failure.

You can build an array of all such `Promises` and pass them to `Promise.allSettled()`. API Ref is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).

For example:

```
const promise1 = myAsyncFunction1();
const promise2 = myAsyncFunction2();

const promisesArray = [promise1, promise2];
const allResponses = await Promise.allSettled(promisesArray);
//Further processing based upon allResponses goes here
```